# Move UITableView down when there are more than a certain number of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a UITableView with dynamic table. It can be 3 to 15 items. 
What I want to do is when there are more than 5 items, I want the uitableView automatically move down to the bottom of the row after appearing the 5th row. How can I do this in Swift?

```
  func animateTable() {
    tableView.reloadData()

    let cells = tableView.visibleCells
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = tableView.bounds.size.height

    for i in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = i as UITableViewCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, tableHeight)
    }

    var index = 0

    for a in cells {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = a as UITableViewCell
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 3.0 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
            }, completion: nil)

        index += 1

        if index >= 3{
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tableData.count - 1, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }


}
```

It just did not do it right.

Comment: when did you run this part of code? after insertion of rows or something?

Comment: Sorry i have edited the question. It should be clearer now. Thanks

Comment: hmm...  If I didn't misunderstand your issue, you want to scroll to 5th row after inserting rows even more that 5 rows right? then I guessed your tableData.count was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. But what's wrong with that? My tableData is just 5-10 different strings var tableData:[string] = ["a", "b", "c", "d" ] and so on...

Comment: I was thinking that you append new data to your `tableData` and do the animation and it's probably incorrect `tableData.count` after doing this. It was 5 and changed to 8. If you want the table view stopped at 6th row, the `tableData.count -1` becomes `8 - 1= 7`. It caused that unexpected scrolling position.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Select viewcontroller in storyboard and uncheck the checkbox of the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** property.